# Getting the value 0 from a float I just set a value to

Tags: android, floating-point

I have 2 methods, 1 that registers the value, and it looks like this:

```
    public void setCordinates(float x, float y, float x2, float y2){
    String str = new String();
    str = "DETAILS. X Value: "+x+". Y Value: "+y;
    Log.d("DETAILZZZ", str);
    str = "DETAILS2222 X Value: "+x2+". Y Value: "+y2;
    Log.d("DETAILZZZ2",str);

    this.x1=(x);
    this.x2=(x2);
    this.y1=(y);
    this.y2=(y2);
    str = "DETAILS. X Value: "+this.x1+". Y Value: "+this.y1;
    Log.d("DETAILZZZ", str);
    str = "DETAILS2222 X Value: "+this.x2+". Y Value: "+this.y2;
    Log.d("DETAILZZZ2",str);
}
```

Into this parameters, I currently pass X Value: 180.0. Y Value: 140.0 and X Value: 520.0. Y Value: 450.0

And logcat gives me the correct value, when I print it out in the method above: Here is the logcat:

```
D/DETAILZZZ2﹕ DETAILS2222 X Value: 520.0. Y Value: 450.0
D/DETAILZZZ﹕ DETAILS. X Value: 180.0. Y Value: 140.0
```

But then In my other method where I need to use this values, logcat displays these variables as zero, here is the code.

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String str = new String();
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    mFinalbitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.planr);
    mFinalbitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mFinalbitmap, getWidth(), getHeight(), true);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    str = "DETAILS----------Width: "+getWidth()+". Heigth: "+getHeight()+". X Value: "+this.x1+". Y Value: "+this.y1;
    Log.d("DETAILZZZ", str);
    str = "DETAILS2222----------Width: "+getWidth()+". Heigth: "+getHeight()+". X Value: "+x2+". Y Value: "+y2;
    Log.d("DETAILZZZ2", str);
    this.x1=((getWidth()/599f)*x1);
    this.x2=((getWidth()/599f)*x2);
    this.y1=((getHeight()/740f)*y1);
    this.y2=((getHeight()/740f)*y2);

    canvas.drawBitmap(mFinalbitmap, 0, 0, null);
    canvas.drawCircle(x1, y1, 30, paint);
    canvas.drawCircle(x2, y2, 30, paint);
}
```

Logcat gives this:

```
DETAILS----------Width: 1080. Heigth: 1533. X Value: 0.0. Y Value: 0.0
D/DETAILZZZ2﹕ DETAILS2222----------Width: 1080. Heigth: 1533. X Value: 0.0.          Y Value: 0.0
```

EDIT: Full code not necessary, doesnt give any helpfull info.

Comment: show us the full code

Comment: One possible explanation is that the two methods are being run in different threads. In particular, if you need to access the data in the event handling thread, you need to set it there.

Comment: Full code added.
How would I be able to determine if its running in diffrent threads ?

Comment: `Looper.myLooper() == Looper.getMainLooper()` returns true if UI thread, i.e. the main thread.